# Z-index not working in iframe IE8 and IE7

Tags: css, iframe, z-index

I have a problem with navigation tabs on my site.
dropdown navigation config to iframe youtub video.

Style CSS For Banner:

```
.banner {
    background-image: url(images/banner-bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left; 
    height: 291px; 
    width: 544px; 
    padding: 7px; 
    z-index:2 !important; 
    position:relative;
}
```

Style CSS For Navigation:

```
.juizdropdown {
    position: relative;
    z-index:999999 !important;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm sure many people here would like to help, but that would be easier if we could quickly reproduce your problem. You should also clearly state what the problem actually is. The CSS is a good start, but without the HTML, it's a bit difficult to actually see what could be going wrong. Set up a minimal example webpage that demonstrates the problem and link that here, or post the HTML to go with the CSS. That said, you might check if .banner and .juizdropdown are siblings in the element hierarchy - IIRC, document structure is more important for draw order than z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to show the dropdown above the embed YouTube video? The wmode property of flash movies can make them appear above all HTML.

Quick test: Why don't you try it with an image in the place of the flash video. If the dropdown appears ok, it's probably the flash wmode?